Are 사자 (lion) & 사장 (boss) related?
Since lion is the leader of the jungle and a boss is the leader of a company/organisation?

They are unrelated.
As described in Wiktionary:

사자 "lion" has hanja spelling 獅子 and comes from Middle Chinese 獅子, which in Zhengzhang Shangfang's reconstruction was /ʃˠiɪ t͡sɨX/.

사장 "director" has hanja spelling 社長 and may possibly be borrowed from Japanese 社長 (IPA: [ɕa̠t͡ɕo̞ː], Hepburn: shachō) or Mandarin 社長 (IPA: /ʂɤ⁵¹ ʈ͡ʂɑŋ²¹⁴⁻²¹⁽⁴⁾/, Pinyin: shèzhǎng), both of which consist of morphemes of Chinese origin, which in Middle Chinese in Zhengzhang Shangfang's reconstruction were /d͡ʑiaX/ and /ʈɨɐŋX/.



Oh, thank you. I did have an inkling that they might be from Chinese.

Are you sure that the word 社長 existed in Middle Chinese? It's clearly made of 會社(회사, company) + 長 and I thought 會社 meaning "company" is a modern Japanese invention...

@jick I improved description.
